# I get the prompt (myusername): ~$ when trying to start my laptop (Ubuntu 12.04.4)

Tags: startup

When I turned on my laptop this morning, it asked me to log in (which it normally doesn't do) and once I logged in, it showed this:

```
(myusername): ~$
```

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.4, and don't know what command I have to type in to get to my desktop page.

Comment: Try `Ctrl + Alt + F7`.

Comment: Try `sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm start`